# Regex.union doesn't match multiline string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to match this content:

```
[default]
aws_secret_access_key = 69bbTs4LcLIRC5zEQxNxEF6FQJI92pdPJe8HHhoEzDnmtS6I
aws_access_key_id = K3YD33nX3u3jeTHWaSnpUw3S66SHpD5cSF
```

against this union:

```
aws_configuration_file_regex = Regexp.union [
  /aws_access_key_id\s*=\s*(?<aws_access_key_id>.+)/,
  /aws_secret_access_key\s*=\s*(?<aws_secret_access_key>.+)/
]
```

but it doesn't work as expected as only the first match present in result:

```
  => #<MatchData
  "aws_secret_access_key =   69bbTs4LcLIRC5zEQxNxEF6FQJI92pdPJe8HHhoEzDnmtS6I"
     aws_secret_access_key:"69bbTs4LcLIRC5zEQxNxEF6FQJI92pdPJe8HHhoEzDnmtS6I"
aws_access_key_id:nil>
```

How to fix that? I'd like to keep the code as short as possible, i.e. no function defines should be present.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Regexp.union` effectively means *match one **or** the other*. It might be best to first match one, then the other.

---

If you still want to match both in one go (as I see you have differently named groups, you have to concatenate them instead and add a multiline flag:

```
# note the .*? for concatenation and the //m flag
r = /aws_secret_access_key\s*=\s*(?<aws_secret_access_key>.+).*?aws_access_key_id\s*=\s*(?<aws_access_key_id>.+)/m

foo.match(r) # =>
  # #<MatchData
  # "aws_secret_access_key = 69bbTs4LcLIRC5zEQxNxEF6FQJI92pdPJe8HHhoEzDnmtS6I\n  aws_access_key_id = K3YD33nX3u3jeTHWaSnpUw3S66SHpD5cSF"
  # aws_secret_access_key:"69bbTs4LcLIRC5zEQxNxEF6FQJI92pdPJe8HHhoEzDnmtS6I\n  "
  # aws_access_key_id:"K3YD33nX3u3jeTHWaSnpUw3S66SHpD5cSF">
```

However, note that this is not the most comprehensive code in the word.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about different groups in the first place. Probably I need to handle it too. But my point was to mach different unordered lines withing single union. Obviously, I want to have all matches. But anyway, you're right. I need to match against array of regexp's and collect the result.

Comment: @user4674453, generally speaking, if you want to find all matches of given regex, you can use `scan` instead of `match`.

Comment: `scan` gives me this:

    `[["69bbTs4LcLIRC5zEQxNxEF6FQJI92pdPJe8HHhoEzDnmtS6I", nil], [nil, "K3YD33nX3u3jeTHWaSnpUw3S66SHpD5cSF"]]`

I fail to imagine readable code to extract the data.

Comment: @user4674453, yea, that is because there are two groups and when one matches, the other one doesn't... As for not-so-terrible: `scan_result.flatten.compact`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work, as lines can be in different order.

Comment: @user4674453, well then you will have to match the regexes one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
((aws_access_key_id\s*=\s*(?<aws_access_key_id>.+))|(aws_secret_access_key\s*=\s*(?<aws_secret_access_key>.+)))*
```

Seems to work on http://rubular.com/

This will collect all the keys, and make a bunch of matches, so you have to sort through that.  Highly recommend you try on rubular.com, and get what is happening, and even tune up the pattern.

Comment: This regex matches incorrectly  when I put lines in different order like this:

```
    [default]
    aws_access_key_id = K3YD33nX3u3jeTHWaSnpUw3S66SHpD5cSF
    aws_secret_access_key = 69bbTs4LcLIRC5zEQxNxEF6FQJI92pdPJe8HHhoEzDnmtS6I
```

Comment: sorry, I was missing something:  you have to surround the whole thing with (...)* so it keeps matching.  This will generate a lot of matches for blanks, but your keys will be there, and easy to detect.